# How to implement nested class and abstract class with pyjnius?(kivy)

Tags: kivy, pyjnius

I want to implement nested class with pyjnius
in python.It is required for developing a feature for plyer.I skimmed the [docs](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

With your class try something like:

```
class _CallbackManagerFactory(JavaClass):
__javaclass__ = 'com/facebook/CallbackManager$Factory'
```

Answer (score 0):

using a dollar sign like this:

```
NestedClass = autoclass('com.package.name.Class$NestedClass')
```